# How can I add elements to X-Axis but not change the scaling?

Tags: javascript, recharts

I'm trying to add some new different elements to the X-axis between constant element that should not move from their position.
In other words, I **don't** want to change the 'scale' of the X-axis,just to add more element to it.

For example, let's say I have this chart, and I want to add some new different elements like a red 'X':

[image]

And i want it to look like this:
[image]

**Edit:**
Whoever encountered this problem, one solution I found is to change the x-axis to be with the following attr :

```
       <XAxis dataKey="date" scale="time" type="number" domain={date[0].date,data[date.length-1].date}/>
```

where "date" is key in `data`
for more information : http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis

Comment: Why would the scale change if the start and end values are the same? Do you have a demonstration to show?

Comment: @isherwood because it will re-calculate the space between the items

Comment: So time isn't represented uniformly? I see now that the first segment is a partial month, yet it occupies 1/3 of the y-axis length. That's unfortunate.